# Scrapy ImportError: cannot import name "______Item"

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am new to python 2.7 & Scrapy, and receive the following error when running "scrapy crawl prop$" from the command line.  I assume this is a simple fix, thus, any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Error Message:

```
  File"C:\Anaconda2\propub\propub\spiders\propub_spider.py", line 4, in <module>
    from propub.items import propubItem
ImportError: cannot import name propubItem
```

`items.py`:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PropubItem(scrapy.Item):
    payee = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    city = scrapy.Field()
    state = scrapy.Field()
    company = scrapy.Field()
    amount =  scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

`propub_spiders.py`:

```
import scrapy 
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor 
from propub.items import propubItem

class propubSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'prop$'
    allowed_domains = ['https://projects.org']
    start_urls = [
        'https://projects/search?state%5Bid%5D=33',
        'https://projects/search?page=2&state%5Bid%5D=33',
        'https://projects/search?page=3&state%5Bid%5D=33']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\\search?page=\\d')), 'parse_start_url', follow=True),)

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="payments_list"]/tbody'):
            item = propubItem()
            item['payee'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[1]/a[2]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]/@href').extract()
            item['city'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['state'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['company'] = sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[4]').extract()
            item['amount'] =  sel.xpath('tr[1]/td[7]/span/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: class name is PropubItem not propubItem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a typo. Your item class name *starts with an upper case letter*.

Replace:

```
from propub.items import propubItem
```

with:

```
from propub.items import PropubItem
```

Comment: hi, would you mind give a help on this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493417/scrapy-import-module-items-error