# Scrapy import module items error

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

My project structure:

```
kmss/
├── kmss
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── first.py
├── README.rst
├── scrapy.cfg
└── setup.py
```

I am running it on mac and my project folder is created at the location: `/user/username/kmss`

And within `items.py` I do have a class named `" KmssItem "`.
If I am going to run the `first.py` ( my spider), I have to import `items.py.`, which is at a higher level.

I am having problem with the following line:

```
from kmss.items import KmssItem
```

Within `items.py`, the codes are:

```
from scrapy import Item, Field

class KmssItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    ##image_urls= Field()
    ##Images = Field()
    title = Field()
    ##url= Field()
    pass
```

Code for `first.py`

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider , Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from kmss.items import KmssItem


class FirstSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "first"
    ## you do not find it to go to facebook links 
    allowed_domains = ["www.reddit.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/',
    ## some other codes
```

I am using anaconda spyder and I have added the path `/users/username/kmss/kmss` to path manager.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/username/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 78, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/Users/username/kmss/kmss/spiders/first.py", line 4, in <module>
    from kmss.items import KmssItem
ImportError: No module named kmss.items
```

Could anyone give a help on this?

Thank you in advance

[Updated]:

**When i run the first.py at spyder, it showed the same error
However, if I run in anaconda command prompt, the error did not happen.**

Comment: import module items error.
I have just added it above

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I tried at spyder python console and at mac terminal
'scrapy crawl first'

Comment: @ZéRicardo may you please help:)
i am having the same problems even I recreated projects

Comment: The folder structure and the code look fine. ```scrapy crawl first``` should work from the project's root dir. I'd deactivate anaconda and try to run it in a new virtualenv, just to be sure.

Comment: I did not create a virtualenv for scraping.. would it be the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be the problem, but testing on a new virtualenv will remove  inconsistencies you may have in your current environment (possibly in your import path).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83719/discussion-between-yukclam9-and-ze-ricardo).

Answer (score 0):

Please try `from ..items import KmssItem`
[P.S. Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)